# Programmatic way to obtain Ruby keywords

Tags: ruby, keyword

I have an Array in Ruby, with all keywords.

For instance:

```
RUBY_KEYWORDS = %w(

  alias and BEGIN begin break case class def defined 
  do else elsif END end ensure false for if in module 
  next nil not or redo rescue retry return self super 
  then true undef unless until when while yield

)
```

My question is simple:

Is there an in-built way to programmatically access all keywords?

Some of my projects need to run a query against user input,
and it's a bit annoying to have to define the same array in
all these projects.

Comment: What kind of query do you run? Why do you need to check the input against this list of keywords? Do you `eval` the input? What about other Ruby methods that might be dangerous (e.g. `FileUtils.rm_r`)?

Comment: I complete the previous question with a quotation from Matz: "_The Ruby parser is flexible and does not complain if you prefix these keywords with @, @@ or $ prefixes and use them as instance, class or global variable names. The best practice is to treat these keywords as reserved._". Also, if you think you shouldn't accept inputs with these keywords, it could be an error. Thus I repeat the question : why do you need the keywords list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code :)

```ruby
RubyToken::TokenDefinitions.select { |definition| definition[1] == RubyToken::TkId }
                           .map { |definition| definition[2] }
                           .compact
                           .sort

# returns :
# ["BEGIN", "END", "__FILE__", "__LINE__", "alias", "and", "begin", "break", "case", "class", "def", "defined?", "do", "else", "elsif", "end", "ensure", "false", "for", "if", "in", "module", "next", "nil", "not", "or", "redo", "rescue", "retry", "return", "self", "super", "then", "true", "undef", "unless", "until", "when", "while", "yield"]
```

Comment: It's interesting that the [keyword table in ruby source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_2/defs/keywords) includes `__ENCODING__`. This code returns all but that one.

Comment: You should probably mention that this is part of the `irb` library in the stdlib, not the core library, so you will have to `require 'irb/ruby-token'` first. Also, it is well known that IRb's parser is buggy, so the results you get here won't necessarily match the Ruby spec. And, it's undocumented, so may change without notice.

Comment: This seems to work, thanks! I'll stick to it until something better will come along. :)

Comment: This no longer works for me in Ruby 2.7. Maybe you can still get this out of ripper or something. My workaround was to pull it out of YARD, where it seems to be included: `YARD::Parser::Ruby::Legacy::RubyToken::TokenDefinitions`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, since it will be defined in the parser.

Your alternative would be to look at the source code: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_1/defs/keywords

Comment: First off: `Object.methods` will *not* show the methods on the `Object` class, it will show the methods that the `Object` *object* responds to, which are basically the methods of the `Class` class not the `Object` class, because `Object` is an instance of `Class`. What you want is `Object.instance_methods`. However, neither `Object.instance_methods` nor `Object.constants` is going to show you the keywords. It is going to show the methods and constants (duh!)